# is it possible to push 2 tableviews in one cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I am working on an app where I want the user to be able to choose whatever country they choose then a `tableview` with in that chosen country with cities and when they choose a city they get to an additional `viewcontroller` with a `tableview` that shows posts of that chosen city.

for instance if it looked like this Sweden->Stockholm->postTableView

I have looked around a bit but i didn't find anything that really would help.

*I do have a normal tableview set up right now with only countries.*

Comment: You could use a navigation controller where you push a new tableview with cities after they select a country or you could use sections in your tableview with the second city section populated based on a selection in your first “country”section.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. 
Create CountriesViewController show list of countries there, on didSelectRow push to CitiesViewController with selected country. show list of cities for this country.
Finally after selecting City push to another ViewController lets say PostsViewController and fetch posts for this city and country and show them

Comment: i dont know if i did it right or not but all my country cells show the same citys  and i dont even know how to create this with diffrent citys it sounded so much easier in my head,  do you have an other idea or and other method i can use so that the user can do this ?

Comment: or do i have to do this manually? like one viewcontroller for each and every city ?